# Account settings without app preferences activity

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-account

Sorry for my bad English!

I am implemented a syncadapter an android app and want to make account settings, such as Google accout settings. Google account has three groups of settings (search, location, ads), each of them opens a separate activity. I have only one setting, without groups.
Сan I call ListPreference immediately instead of open activity, duplicate setting in this new activity and launch ListPreference?

**Update 1:**
I want to create one setting to my own account. Account has already been created.
When I click on this setting, then open the settings app, where I again click on the settings and see ListPreference. I want to click on the setting in AccountManager and immediately see ListPreference, without showing app preference activity.
Is this possible or not?

Comment: ilya, your question is quite unclear, can you please clarify it more in detail?

Comment: @pratik, I added details

Comment: @ilya, could you please share the code of your activity, which starts when you click on settings in AccountManager? And also share the code of intent for AccountManager settings.

Comment: @lobzik Thanks, I already figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to open activity, and then within this activity to open the settings.